# Configure TinyMCE Tag Use (Strong->B, etc) (Django-tinymce)

Tags: django-tinymce

So, I'm looking through the documentation, and unfortunately it stops short of offering any sort of explanation on how the normal TinyMCE format translates into the settings.py TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG dictionary.

Basically, I need to configure it so that bold is represented as b, not strong, and other similar changes.

Does anyone have a syntax example they could share for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, it turns out, using:

django-tinymce4-lite

As my library, the way this is done is:

1. Try adjusting the formatting for inline to use the different element
2. If it's still persistent, add the element to the extended_valid_elements
3. Finally, if it really won't stop using strong and em, blacklist those tags

   ```
   'formats': {
     'bold':{'inline': 'b'},
     'underline':{'inline': 'u'},
     'italic':{'inline': 'i'},
    }
   ```

and later:

```
extended_valid_elements:'u,b,i'
```

finally:

```
invalid_elements:'em strong'
```